# Getting Alpine Touring (a.k.a Randonee) boots for big feet

Tags: boots, alpine-touring

I wear US 14 / Euro 48 size shoes, and Alpine Touring / Randonee boots don't appear to be available at online retailers (e.g. REI and Backcountry.com) despite some manufacturers making them in this size.

Where can I buy Alpine Touring / Randonee boots in these sizes?

Comment: It might help to shop in an area where that size is more the norm. In the Netherlands size 48 is not considered extreme, just big, and many stores stock the size and even bigger as a standard option. (Their online stores should as well.) Now, if you go to 56, you need a speciallity shop for big sizes here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more research, it appears the only manufacturer that makes boots in a Mondo 32 (the direct equivalent of a US 14) is Scarpa. The two online retailers I found that sell Scarpa AT boots in these large sizes are [OMCgear](http://www.omcgear.com) and [Bent Gate Mountaineering](http://www.bentgate.com/); though, the Canadian company [Mountain Equipment Co-op](http://www.mec.ca) is also selling them in these sizes.

**Update**
I bought the stiffer version of the Maestrale (white), and I have had a terrible time with pain in my feet from them. I've had the boxed out once as they do indeed run narrow (may do it again), but it seems to be do to my arch support once they're buckled down now. If I were buying again, I think I would go with the cheaper less rigid orange version.

Answer (score 3):

I bought some scarpa maestrale rs in a size 32. Although scarpa list them in this size, they only make them if there are orders. I preordered mine from 3 different UK retailers in Feb 2012, and only one retailer managed to successfully get them into stock by october 2012. They are fantastic boots, and the only ones that come in this size so make sure you get your order in for next season asap.